# Encountering a problem when trying to remove some code from a route to put it into a service - Node.js / Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having a problem right now when i want to remove some code out of my route to put it into a service. I'm just trying to follow the best practices of developing an application.

This is my route right now:

```
const express = require('express');

const cityRouter = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');
const NodeCache = require('node-cache');

const myCache = new NodeCache();

cityRouter.get('/:cep', async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const { cep } = request.params;

    const value = myCache.get(cep);

    if (value) {
      response.status(200).send({
        city: value,
        message: 'Data from the cache',
      });
    } else {
      const resp = await axios.get(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/`);
      myCache.set(cep, resp.data, 600);

      response.status(200).send({
        city: resp.data,
        message: 'Data not from the cache',
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return response.status(400);
  }
});

module.exports = cityRouter;
```

I'm using axios to retrieve data from an API, where i have a variable called "cep" as a parameter and then using node-cache to cache it.

And it works with out problems:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpFL0.png)

But, when i try to put the same code into a service, and then call it into my route:

**My service**:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const NodeCache = require('node-cache');

const myCache = new NodeCache();

function verificaCache(cep) {
  return async function (request, response, next) {
    const value = myCache.get(cep);

    console.log(cep);

    if (value) {
      response.status(200).send({
        city: value,
        message: 'Data from the cache',
      });
    } else {
      const resp = await axios.get(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/`);
      myCache.set(cep, resp.data, 600);

      response.status(200).send({
        city: resp.data,
        message: 'Data not from the cache',
      });
    }
    next();
  };
}

module.exports = verificaCache;
```

**My route using the service**:

```
const express = require('express');

const cityRouter = express.Router();

const verificaCache = require('../services/VerificaCacheService');

cityRouter.get('/:cep', async (request, response) => {
  const { cep } = request.params;

  verificaCache(cep);

  response.status(200);
});

module.exports = cityRouter;
```

By some reason, it doesn't work:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QhMM.png)

What is the problem that i can't see? I'm a beginner so i'm kinda lost right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a high-order function by returning a function in `verificaCache()`, so to properly call it you need to do it like that `await verificaCache(cep)(req, res)`, remember, the first time you call it, you have a function being returned, since you want the tasks inside of that function to be executed, you need to call it as well.

Take a reading about high-order functions here: https://blog.alexdevero.com/higher-order-functions-javascript/

My recommendation, you could just get rid of the other function you are returning to simplify your code, and let the service only handle business logic, all the http actions should be handled on the controller level:

```
// Service
function verificaCache(cep) {
  const value = myCache.get(cep);

  if (value) {
    return { city: value, message: 'Data from the cache'})
  }

  // No need of an else statement because the 
  // execution will stop at the first return if the condition passes
  const resp = await axios.get(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/`);

  myCache.set(cep, resp.data, 600);

  return { city: resp.data, message: 'Data not from the cache'};
}

// Controller
cityRouter.get('/:cep', async (request, response) => {
  const { cep } = request.params;

  try {
    const data = verificaCache(cep);
    // Use json() instead of send()
    response.status(200).json(data); 
  } catch(error) {
    // Handle errors here
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Estamos juntos!

Comment: Brabo demais... I just had to put an "async" on the function because i'm using await inside it, and then put an "await" on "const data = await verificaCache(cep);".
Thank you! Tamo junto!

Comment: By the way, do you know how i could put this data into a database? Do you have a good link to send that explains it? Thank you anyway for the help.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend doing database operations using an ORM such as Sequelize or Knex.js. Take a look at this article: https://lorenstewart.me/2016/10/03/sequelize-crud-101/